# Page moves on radio/star select

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I'm using the code found here for multiple CSS star rating radios: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27067571/2520920

```css
.rating {
  float: left;
}
.rating:not(:checked) > input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.rating:not(:checked) > label {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  padding: 0 .1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 200%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #ddd;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #bbb, 2px 2px #666, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.rating:not(:checked) > label:before {
  content: &#9733;
}
.rating > input:checked ~ label {
  color: #ff7700;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #c60, 2px 2px #940, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
  color: gold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.rating> input:checked + label:hover,
.rating> input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rating> input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating> input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rating> label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
  color: #ea0;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.rating > label:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="meals">Meals</label>
  <div class="controls rating one">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="meals" value="5" />
    <label for="star5"><span>&#9733</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="meals" value="4" />
    <label for="star4"><span>&#9733</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="meals" value="3" />
    <label for="star3"><span>&#9733</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="meals" value="2" />
    <label for="star2"><span>&#9733</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="meals" value="1" />
    <label for="star1"><span>&#9733</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<!--added so that you can see the page jump--->
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="lodging">Lodging</label>
  <div class="controls rating two">
    <input type="radio" id="star5-1" name="lodging" value="5" />
    <label for="star5-1"><span>&#9733</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4-1" name="lodging" value="4" />
    <label for="star4-1"><span>&#9733</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3-1" name="lodging" value="3" />
    <label for="star3-1"><span>&#9733</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2-1" name="lodging" value="2" />
    <label for="star2-1"><span>&#9733</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1-1" name="lodging" value="1" />
    <label for="star1-1"><span>&#9733</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<!--added so that you can see the page jump--->
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="trans">Transportation</label>
  <div class="controls rating three">
    <input type="radio" id="star5-2" name="trans" value="5" />
    <label for="star5-2"><span>&#9733</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4-2" name="trans" value="4" />
    <label for="star4-2"><span>&#9733</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3-2" name="trans" value="3" />
    <label for="star3-2"><span>&#9733</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2-2" name="trans" value="2" />
    <label for="star2-2"><span>&#9733</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1-2" name="trans" value="1" />
    <label for="star1-1"><span>&#9733</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Every time I click a star rating, the page jumps to the top. I've played quite a bit with the `.rating > label:active` CSS properties - I can make the page stand still but the star ratings don't work.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Make sure to set an height for your element(s) in question. Also radio buttons act very different in each browser, best way to fix it is to add inside a span, givetje span  a height and width and your done.

Comment: @RensTillmann - that doesn't seem to be working `<span style="height:50px; width:250px;">` is what I'm trying around each control-group. Am I missing something?

Comment: No give your input fields and labels a height and a border to see what is going on. Or just add border on all elements, it will give you a clear view of where and what is causing your problem. It's hard to tell just by reading your code.

Comment: You say page goes all the way to top (instantly) when clicking on star? That must be an external script, this can only be the cause.

Comment: Could you try to disable all js files?

Comment: @RensTillmann disabled all JS files this morning. still jumps to the top. :(

this application is running on Bootstrap 2 if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Make your position fixed from absolute.

Here

```
.rating:not(:checked) > input {
  position: fixed;
  top: -9999px;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```